# How to use JFileChooser for client side?

Tags: java, linux, server, client, jfilechooser

I have a program which saves csv file into the user's PC.
I used JFilechooser, and it works fine with local server.
However, after I deployed the program on the server (linux) and used it on my PC (window), it doesn't work.

```
public String fileChooser()
{
    String csvPath;

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    int userSelection = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    System.out.println("userSelection : "+userSelection);

    if(userSelection != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select the path.");
        System.out.println("Not open");
        csvPath = null;
    }else{
        csvPath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        System.out.println("csvPath :"+csvPath);
    }
    return csvPath;
}
```

How to use JFileChooser to save files to the client's side?

Comment: `JFileChooser` is used to locate a file *on the local filesystem* either for opening or for saving. It cannot be used to locate a remote file unless it's mounted locally. Perhaps you should [edit] your question and add a [mcve] that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks and I added some codes.